# Why does my Puppet template return true instead of the output from awk?

Tags: ruby, linux, templates, puppet, erb

I want to calculate memory on the fly to set sysctl values. My `db.erb` template contains:

```
hugepage = <%= system "grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo|awk '{print $2}'" %>
```

but it's just printing `true` in the final output. If I run the following command in the `irb` shell it will work:

```
[root@localhost templates]# irb
irb(main):001:0> system "grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo|awk '{print $2}'"
2048
=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) does. The documentation is very clear about what it returns:

> system returns true if the command gives zero exit status, false for non zero exit status. Returns nil if command execution fails.

If you want to insert the *output* of your command rather than the system method's return value into your template, then you want to use backticks or %x instead. For example:

```
hugepage = <%= `grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'` %>
```

Comment: I am trying following but it is not performing `awk` operation also why? `$hugepage=inline_template("<%= ``grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'`` %>")`

Comment: @Satish 1) You're asking a different question. 2) Why are you doubling the backticks? That is unlikely to do anything useful.

Comment: That is not double tick there, I was trying to formate my code in comment section. Just ignore double ticks.